# Apple watch user session management

Tags: ios, iphone, session, watchkit, apple-watch

How can we handle user session management in apple watch? Especially in watch OS 1 where we can only request data from watch to the host iPhone app.
Also an example or a tutorial will be of great help.
How do watch apps like twitter and Instagram handle user sessions, covering up all the scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean session in the context of authentication?

If so, the way I've done it (at least in watch OS 1) is to request an Auth token from the parent app (the same one it would use for its operations) at the start of the watch app which remains cached in the parent app for later service calls.

If a valid token isn't found or it expires, the parent app will call an authentication method in the service to retrieve one. If that fails, the watch app will display a global message saying that the user must update their credentials from their phone before continuing.